# Problem substraction timestamp in Excel on date part

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried to substraction a timestamp in Excel, But I have a curious result, see yourself :

The data:

```
04/03/2020 10:58:00,626
04/03/2020 10:58:21,054
```

Calculation:

```
Data                     Result
04/03/2020 10:58:00,626  00/01/1900 00:00:17,145
04/03/2020 10:58:21,054
```

I don't understand why I have the problem on the date part (year 1900)... The format is like

```
jj/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss,000
```

Comment: Because you format your result including the year etc. the result shows the year, but since it's 0 it shows the year month and date for the excel datevalue equals 0.

Comment: So what can I do ?

Comment: Jolly roger explained it further. If you change to numeric you get the difference. (You might need to multiply by 24 to get the hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the format to numeric, you will probably get a hint.
Computers store and calculate dates as a number; In case of Excel it's the number of days since 31.12.1899 00:00:00 - wich in Excel is presented as 00/01/1900 for some reason i don't know.
So you're basically calculating something like 43894.457 - 43894.456 and you end up with 0.001 -> the date 31.12.1800 00:00:00 plus 0.001 Days.